# AngularJS interceptor @q not handling multipart requests?

Tags: angularjs, multipartform-data

I have an interceptor which works fine and adds authentication headers to all my requests.

All ? Well, I thought so. But now that I'm adding a file upload feature to my application, I cannot see the interceptor kicking in when uploading the file.

The file upload request is sent and the server responds with a 401 Access is denied.

Here is my interceptor:

```
utilsModule.factory('AuthInterceptor',
  ['$q', 'AuthService', 'CacheCredentialsService',
  function($q, AuthService, CacheCredentialsService) {
    return {
      'request': function(config) {
        console.log("Intercepting request", config);
        if (config.url.indexOf("admins/login") == -1) {
          console.log("Adding authentication headers");
          config.headers.Authorization = AuthService.getCredentialsHeaders(CacheCredentialsService.getLoggedInAdminEmail(), CacheCredentialsService.getLoggedInAdminPassword());
        } else {
          config.headers.Authorization = '';
        }

        return config;
      },
      'requestError': function(rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
      'response': function(response) {
        return response;
      },
      'responseError': function(rejection) {
        if (rejection.status == 401) {
          CacheCredentialsService.destroyLoggedInAdmin();
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

None of the console log statements are displayed on the upload request (they are on all other requests).

All the upload request headers as seen in the browser console log:

```
POST /nitro-project-rest/bts/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 299
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryf1GHBVkgYB1HbK2I
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,et;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,sv;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
```

And the upload request payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryf1GHBVkgYB1HbK2I
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="europlasma.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Are you using angular file upload?

Comment: Yes i am, it works fine with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular-Fileuplaod does not use Angular's `$http` service then your only resort is to use the properties in the **`FileUploader`** Service.

```
var uploader = new FileUploader({
    headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer Your-token'
    },
    formData: {
       extraData: 'This is an extra data'
    }
});

uploader.onErrorItem = function(item, response, status, headers) {
    if(status === 401) {
        // do your thing
    }
};
```

Comment: How to trigger the uploader.onErrorItem handler ? My REST handler returns a BAD_REQUEST status response with a message but it does not get picked up by the AngularJS file upload error handler. My server response: {
  "url" : "http://localhost:8080/project-rest/bts/upload",
  "httpStatus" : "BAD_REQUEST",
  "message" : "The csv parser could not parse the file as it was expecting the following format: btsId, name",
  "developerMessage" : "",
  "errorCode" : ""
}

Comment: Are you using the status == 401? if you are, then you should use status == 400 for Bad Request.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit maybe. It's not about the status. Of course, it is not a 401. It's just that the onErrorItem handler does not kick in. I wonder what it takes to have it kicking in.

Comment: in your network console, what status does your response give?

Comment: You can see it in my above comment. It was copy pasted from the browser console. But it is not trickling up to the file upload page. This page is in fact a modal overlay from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I was hoping a given 404 or 401 or any non 200 http status would trigger the file upload onErrorItem handler.

Comment: In fact, my file uploads just fine. So it is the onCompleteItem that fires. And it does contain the error code and message. I was just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, now, it's fine, I just need to display the error message.